Why did Kora drop the energy sword like it was hot?
In the sci-fi film Rebel Moon – Part Two: The Scargiver (2024), there's a sequence of events that confused me. It's the one where Kora is fighting an Imperium soldier wielding a Krypteian sword (an energy sword sort of like a lightsaber) aboard the King's Gaze dreadnought.
As they were fighting, Kora managed to disarm the soldier, take his sword, and stab him right in the gut. Here's where it gets confusing for me: after stabbing the soldier, Kora yanks the sword out and drops it like it's hot.

So, my burning question is: If the sword was too hot to handle, how did the soldier wield it in the first place, and how did Kora manage to stab him with it before dropping it? She would've released the sword the second she grabbed it if it was scorching hot (withdrawal reflex).
Why did Kora drop the sword like it was hot after using it like it wasn't hot on the Imperium soldier? Did I miss some crucial detail about how these Krypteian swords work?

FWIW, it seems the sword is a "Krypteian Sword".

Perhaps the pimp was in the crib, ma

Maybe it was hot?

@FuzzyBoots I see. I added the term used for the sword to my question.


So she wields the sword whilst it is still hot and powered on (power source in hilt). She doesnt have enough time to protect her hands from it, she just needs to get the job done quickly (killing the soldier).
The sword is already sharp, but the power source makes it better in penetrating power (based upon technique used).
The dropping of the sword is a nod to the audience to reinforce the idea that these are hot swords, and she is a tough soldier cookie. Tougher than the normal soldiers who use it with gloves.
This is showing the audience that she is tough enough to hold the sword without gloves just long enough to kill the soldier, also reinforcing that she is the hero character.
Note that she wraps the hilt to protect her hands when using it in further battles.
ref:

For close combat, "They have their oracle-steel
swords, that are externally powered," Snyder explains.
"There's a little power unit on them.
Clumsy wiring, crude, Those are unlike Nemesis's swords, which are made of the same
kind of metal but are more elegant because her power source is her. She's more in
harmony with her swords.
The Krypteians have had to retrofit and glue things
on to make them work, and so defile the beautiful symmetry of the thing.
That's why they wear those gloves, so they can hold the swords. It's
kind of like an oven mitt."


P176, Rebel Moon: Creating a Galaxy: Worlds and Technology
By Peter Aperlo / 2023 / ISBN:9781803366111, 1803366117
https://rebel-moon.fandom.com/wiki/Weapons#cite_note-2

Yikes. That quote is from something that was written by the studio? No wonder the film was such a runaway success :-)

@Valorum - i finally gave up and fast forwarded through the film - remove the slow motion and farming parts, the film is probably about 5 minutes long. Should have stayed a young adults short story.

Appalling film, great answer. Gotcha

I was also confused by this (and other things like people using shovels to feed coal into the engines of the King's Gaze.  WTF?!?!?!?)
There is some parallel to Kora not initially burning herself with the exposition of Nemesis' use of her light sabres molten metal swords.  In the flashback to Nemesis' origin, we see her

 Take the swords out of the their case, and then use them to cut off each of her own hands, which are then replaced with the mechanical hands that are also in the case.  According to this site, the mechanical hands allow her to control the swords.

Thus, Kora may be able to initially use the soldier's swords with little issues but requires extra protection to fully wield them.
Or .. she has slow reflexes, and it took a while for her brain to realize that her hands were burning in the adrenaline of the fight.

Note that I deny ever watching this movie, and if I did it was because I was only in the middle of a Covid-19 induced fever dream.  The same dream that made me hallucinate the spectre of a sequel to all of this.

The withdrawal reflex does exist...but I see 2 things that would effect it:

Kora was a farmer, which means that she has heavily calloused hands.

Speaking as someone who has heavily calloused hands... It takes a while for me to feel heat thru them. So I don't always realize something is hot in the first second of touching it.

Instinctive responses can be overridden.

I have accidently picked up a glass pan which I didn't realize was hot... And then carefully set it back down instead of dropping it because I didn't want to break the pan.

I think Kora was a soldier for a lot longer than she was a farmer /s  But the farming would definitely help with adding callouses.

@PeterM it doesn't take that long to build callouses on your hands thick enough to provide some thermal insulation... A year of hard labor might be enough.

The trick is not minding it hurts.

"heavily calloused hands" - wait, didn't Kora have artificial hands?

@O.R.Mapper does she? Ill admit I have only seen the first one so far

@Questor: I watched both parts just once, and back to back, so I am not sure at what point of the story this was shown.

I got the impression that Nemesis’ orange Oracle swords burn with plasma or something, and the blue Krypteian swords are cold or freezing. That could explain why Kora could hold it for a second without protection. Or they are plasma-like just like Oracle swords with a different color. I’m curious as to other’s opinions.

But if it was burning with plasma, how did the soldier handle it?  Please make sure your post is directed at answering the question.

One thing I noticed is that no one ever wielded a blade bare handed like she did. They all wore gloves, except Nemisis because her blade were different or it was just tradition for those who wielded those blades to sacrifice their forearms.
My theory is that for the blue blades, there is an electrical field generated by the blades and so you have to wear insulated gloves to not get shocked by them. Kora got around that by using the cloth to wrap the handle so that her bare hands wouldn't touch it. To me, she acted more like someone touching a live wire instead of being burned.
